# connect the pi to a windows 7 shared drive via wifi?

Tags: raspbian, windows

I am trying to mount a shared drive from my W7 main computer, to a raspbian release. The pc is connected to the network via wired connection, to a wifi router, while the PI is connected via wifi to the same router.

I tried to mount the drive, but I get an error because the host can't be found:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o user=user,password=123456 //W7PC/Datadisk /mnt/win_disk

mount error:could not resolve address for W7PC: Unknown error
```

I am not sure if the issue is that W7 is on wired network, while the pi is on wifi? Although I am able to connect to this machine from a wifi tablet running windows 8; so I thought that being on wifi should not be an issue.

Any clues about what is the issue here?

Comment: Replace `W7PC` with your windows pc IP. Ie, your windows pc ip is `192.168.1.2`. command should look like : `sudo mount -t cifs -o user=user,password=123456 //192.168.1.2/Datadisk /mnt/win_disk`

Comment: Thanks a lot, the IP works! So I cannot connect to the computer by name but only by IP?

Comment: Have a look at this answer. It explains it in detail. http://askubuntu.com/questions/243461/how-can-i-connect-to-a-samba-server-using-its-hostname-instead-of-the-ip

Comment: @dastaan - you probably could add that as the answer :)

Comment: @Wilf Added. :)

Answer (score 1):

In this case, replace `W7PC` with your Windows PC ip address. ie, suppose your windows pc ip is `192.168.1.2`. command should look like : `sudo mount -t cifs -o user=user,password=123456 //192.168.1.2/Datadisk /mnt/win_disk`

Now coming to the 2nd part, why it is not working with hostname is an entirely different issue and I believe you will get detailed information on that issue by going through [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/243461/how-can-i-connect-to-a-samba-server-using-its-hostname-instead-of-the-ip) link.

Hope it helps.